# Comparar String con un número

Tags: java

¿Cómo comparo un *String* con un *número* en *Java*?

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
String weight = st.nextToken();
if(weight >= 15) {

}
```

Pero sale el siguiente error:

> The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int

¿Cómo puedo compararlo? Sé que ese *token* es un número (estoy leyendo de un fichero con separadores, por eso utilizo *StringTokenizer*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes castear antes, convertir el *string* a *int*

```
String weight = st.nextToken();
if(Integer.parseInt(weight) >= 15) {

}
```

Saludos